# Pin lock vs Ball lock

Tags: corny-keg, keg

When it comes to corny keg disconnects, what are the pros and cons of pin lock vs ball lock posts? Seems like there are more spare parts available for the ball lock kind.

Answer (score 3):

Ball lock tend to be the most available around my parts in MA.  And like you said parts are easier to come by for these too.
As long as you keep the fittings in good working order (i.e. clean them once in a while), they go on and off fairly easily.

The only issue will ball locking posts is that its sometimes difficult to remember which on is the out and which is the in.  At first glance they are very similar, but they are indeed different.  So when you disassemble a keg for cleaning you need to pay close attention to how they go back together.

I think the pin locks are a little more obvious which is which usually.